# Why can't I put the phrase System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyEntity> in my question?

Tags: support, markdown

If I copy the title of this question below it appears as 
Why can't I put the phrase System.Data.Entity.DbSet in my question?

Comment: That's not a code block, but a quote block, so `<tags>` will be swallowed. I fixed it for you

Comment: Code blocks use 4 spaces for indent, not `>`

Comment: Tricky - you just put a phrase in a question saying you can't put it in a question.

Comment: sorry, just re--edited. The problem seems to be apparent of all text in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here has to do with the > & < signs. The parser thinks you are trying to write an HTML tag. [Since only a specific subset of those are allowed, your tag is removed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

The key here is that you need to put the whole thing in a code block. There are two ways to do this. One is to indent the line with 4 spaces, the other is to use backticks to surround it.

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyEntity>
```

The above is a paragraph separated by blank lines that is indented with four spaces. This is used to format blocks of code. If you just wanted to put the phrase in in the middle of something else (like this: `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyEntity>`), you can surround it with backticks (`).

Lastly if you have something with those symbols that is not code and you don't want to format it as such, you can use the HTML replacement code `&lt;` or `&gt;` to produce the > & < symbols instead of entering them directly.